# Statistical method to find the value which preserves the most information inside "most" of data points. (resize images to a common height)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-preprocessing, descriptive-statistics

So I have this data of around 88K images and I found out some interesting properties for my images.

```
print(np.median(width),np.mean(width),scipy.stats.mode(width))
print(np.median(height),np.mean(height),scipy.stats.mode(height))

>>
1280.0 1266.8129869839922 ModeResult(mode=array([1280]), count=array([84584]))
377.0 438.3157888861602 ModeResult(mode=array([125]), count=array([3113]))
```

So I am resizing all of the images to width of `1280` because it'll preserve the images for most of the images when scaling up or down as all of three are same.

But what I want to know is that what should I do for the `height` so that it preserves most of the information. Or to rephrase, to which height I should resize my image so that I can preserve most of the information. In, my opinion, Scaling down is better than scaling up.

```
for q in [0.35,0.55,0.75,0.95,] :
    print(np.quantile(height,q))
>> 274.0
414.0
562.0
1057.0
```

Is there any statistical method so that I can find the appropriate range?

My height data is positively skewed and looks like:
[image]

Black line is the `scipy.stats.norm`

Comment: While it isn't asked, it is a very (impo) fun exercise, you might consider seam carving for your resizing.  [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NcIJXTlugc), [SIGGRAPH paper](https://www.win.tue.nl/~wstahw/edu/2IV05/seamcarving.pdf).  Here is a tutorial on it [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/image-resizing-using-seam-carving-using-opencv-in-python/).  The stats you gave are not for the blue line or bars, but something else, the black line perhaps.  For the approach I wanted to use they are not really that useful.